# When deploying a smart contract, isn't the "owner" of the contract (by default) the one who deploys it?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I am trying to use a function in a flashloan contract that uses the onlyOwner modifier. When I send the flashloan transaction, I get returned the error: "caller is not the owner".

I am using the same account that I used to create the contract when running this flash loan, so I'm not sure why it's not recognizing me as the owner.

You can see here that it is the same address to create the contract and to send the failed transaction.
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x91109bde85e0ab631d1983ce07b910ce4e99078a

Click on the first transaction there ^^ to see the error message.

code of onlyOwner modifier: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol

Contract file

```
    pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "./aave/FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2.sol";
import "../../interfaces/v2/ILendingPoolAddressesProviderV2.sol";
import "../../interfaces/v2/ILendingPoolV2.sol";

contract FlashloanV2 is FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2, Withdrawable {

    constructor(address _addressProvider) FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2(_addressProvider) public {}

    /**
     * @dev This function must be called only be the LENDING_POOL and takes care of repaying
     * active debt positions, migrating collateral and incurring new V2 debt token debt.
     *
     * @param assets The array of flash loaned assets used to repay debts.
     * @param amounts The array of flash loaned asset amounts used to repay debts.
     * @param premiums The array of premiums incurred as additional debts.
     * @param initiator The address that initiated the flash loan, unused.
     * @param params The byte array containing, in this case, the arrays of aTokens and aTokenAmounts.
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        
        //
        // This contract now has the funds requested.
        // Your logic goes here.
        //
        
        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
        // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
        // these amounts.
        
        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
        }

        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            withdraw(assets[i]);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function _flashloan(address[] memory assets, uint256[] memory amounts) internal {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](assets.length);

        // 0 = no debt (flash), 1 = stable, 2 = variable
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            modes[i] = 0;
        }

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    /*
     *  Flash multiple assets 
     */
    function flashloan(address[] memory assets, uint256[] memory amounts) public onlyOwner {
        _flashloan(assets, amounts);
    }

    /*
     *  Flash loan 1000000000000000000 wei (1 ether) worth of `_asset`
     */
    function flashloan(address _asset) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory data = "";
        uint amount = 1 ether;

        address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
        assets[0] = _asset;

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        amounts[0] = amount;

        _flashloan(assets, amounts);
    }
}
```

Withdrawable.sol (where withdraw() function comes from)

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

/**
    Ensures that any contract that inherits from this contract is able to
    withdraw funds that are accidentally received or stuck.
 */
 
contract Withdrawable is Ownable {
    using SafeERC20 for ERC20;
    address constant ETHER = address(0);

    event LogWithdraw(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _assetAddress,
        uint amount
    );

    /**
     * @dev Withdraw asset.
     * @param _assetAddress Asset to be withdrawn.
     */
    function withdraw(address _assetAddress) public onlyOwner {
        uint assetBalance;
        if (_assetAddress == ETHER) {
            address self = address(this); // workaround for a possible solidity bug
            assetBalance = self.balance;
            msg.sender.transfer(assetBalance);
        } else {
            assetBalance = ERC20(_assetAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
            ERC20(_assetAddress).safeTransfer(msg.sender, assetBalance);
        }
        emit LogWithdraw(msg.sender, _assetAddress, assetBalance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the source code of the [contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x91109bde85e0ab631d1983ce07b910ce4e99078a) (or verify it on Etherscan), so it's possible to troubleshoot your issue more easily. However, it seems that the message comes from an internal tx, not from the original tx. Which means that the `msg.sender` is not the end user executing the original tx, but one of the contracts in the chain of transactions. And its address is probably not the `owner`.

Comment: @PetrHejda Sure, I just added the code for my contract and the code for where the withdraw function comes from. I would verify it on etherscan, but I was having difficulty doing so... still kind of new to this